# Values on x-Axes

Tags: plot, wolfram-mathematica

How to place certain values on the x-axis below and other values above in PlotRange. Below must be the calculated values and above values in the range 0-1.

```
ListLinePlot[
 Marker = Log[{97000., 66000., 45000., 30000.}], 
 Ticks -> {{{1, "0.12"}, {2, "0.21"}, {3, "0.38"},
    {4, "0.55"}, {5, ".75"}, {5, "0.7"}, {6, "0.8"},
    {7, "0.9"}, {8, "1."}}, Automatic, {0, 1}},
 Mesh -> All, MeshStyle -> {PointSize[0.03], Red},
 AxesLabel -> {"Rf", "Ln"}, LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, 12],
 PlotLabel -> HoldForm[Marker], AxesOrigin -> {.7, 9.8}, 
 AxesStyle -> Directive[RGBColor[0.00613, 0.444, 0.],
   AbsoluteThickness[1.5]]]
```

[[image]]

Comment: If you have at least MMA 12.3 then there is https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AxisObject.html and it looks like that can be used with something like `Show[ListLinePlot[...], Graphics[AxisObject[{ "Horizontal",11.6,{.1,1}}]], PlotRange->All]` to build and position and display a second axis anywhere on a plot. I've fiddled with it and haven't been yet able to get it to display exactly what you are looking for, but perhaps you will have more luck. I'll keep fiddling and let you know if I succeed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Frame`

```
Marker = HoldForm[Log[{97000., 66000., 45000., 30000.}]];

ListLinePlot[ReleaseHold[Marker], 
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic},
   {{{1, "0.12"}, {2, "0.21"}, {3, "0.38"}, {4, "0.55"},
     {5, ".75"}, {5, "0.7"}, {6, "0.8"}, {7, "0.9"}, {8, "1."}},
    {{1, "0.25"}, {2, "0.5"}, {3, "0.75"}, {4, "1"}}}},
 Mesh -> All, MeshStyle -> {PointSize[0.03], Red},
 FrameLabel -> {"Rf", "Ln"}, LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, 12],
 PlotLabel -> Framed[Marker, FrameStyle -> None],
 AxesOrigin -> {.7, 9.8},
 FrameStyle -> Directive[RGBColor[0.00613, 0.444, 0.],
   AbsoluteThickness[1.5]],
 Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, True}}]
```

[image]

Comment: The frame around `Marker` is just to add some space between the upper axis and the label.